# nginx: How to keep double slashes in urls

Tags: nginx

I have web service which takes several filter parameters, something like :

```
http://mydomain.com/filter1/value1/filter2/value2/filter3/value3
```

The tricky thing is sometimes some of the filter variables are absent, so urls as such could be passed to this service:

```
http://mydomain.com/filter1//filter2//filter3/value3
```

Now I need to configure my nginx (or fastcgi) to keep the double slashes. Currently it's replacing double slashes to single ones. I'm new to nginx & fastcgi configuration and I don't know how to do that. I captured the request_uri from my php script when I requested the second url, and I got

```
http://mydomain.com/filter1/filter2/filter3/value3
```

Plz help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, maybe the question is a better fit into ServerFault.com, could anyone help me transfer it there?

Comment: DONT FORGET to remove trailing slashes in your proxy_pass'es!! It will not work otherwise (nginx 1.8.1).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
syntax: merge_slashes [on|off]
default: merge_slashes on
context: http, server
```

You must use: `merge_slashes off`;

Comment: Thx. But where did you find the documentation. Could you give me a link plz? I googled "nginx merge_slashes" but got nothing to the documentation.

Comment: My native language is russian, so, i found it here: http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

Comment: And I just tried it out, but seems not working. I added merge_slashes off; inside server{ ... }

Comment: Wondering if there's an English version.

Comment: If I have to use double slashes in my url. Is there any other work around?

Comment: somehow does not work in server context, must be in http context

Comment: @Shawn: The English documentation is here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with nginx+passenger (for Ruby on Rails / Rack / etc.), and I confirm that by default, multiple slashes are collapsed (in both `PATH_INFO` and `REQUEST_URI`).

Adding `merge_slashes off;` in the `server` context of the nginx configuration fixed it (I now see multiple slashes alright).

Answer (score 5):

Also, make sure you don't have a trailing slash in the proxy_pass line!

- **GOOD**: `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000`;
- **BAD**: `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/`;

Comment: WOW, I saw your answer accidentally and from curiosity decided to make no slash in my proxy_pass. And it worked!! It should be in first answer OBVIOUSLY. I add it to comments section for that answer

Answer (score 0):

As per previous answers, the solution is to use `merge_slashes off;` in your Nginx config. However, if you use virtual hosts, then it looks like you need to include it in your first host. That is the case on v1.4.1 and v1.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

if the methods posted here don't work try this

```
      proxy_redirect     default;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
```

reference :[running jenkins hehind nginx](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Nginx)