# Using "///" inside a URL in a NGINX/Django project

Tags: regex, django, url, nginx, uri

I have a Django project running with NGINX and I would like to route the following URL to a view:

```
example.com///what.three.words
```

…that is, with the 3 slashes

And it should be a different view than:

```
example.com/what.three.words
```

The following works with the Django test server:

```
url(r'^//(?P<w3w_address>[\w.]+)/?$', W3WView.as_view(), name='w3w')
```

…but not in production with NGINX and Gunicorn (the URL redirects to the homepage). The question is why, is NGINX somehow messing with it?

NGINX config:

```
upstream project_prod {

        server unix:/webapps/project/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

        listen 80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com amp.domain.com;

        keepalive_timeout 5;
        client_max_body_size 4G;

        access_log /webapps/project/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /webapps/project/logs/nginx-error.log;

        location /.well-known/ {
                alias /webapps/project/.well-known/;
        }

        location /static/ {
                alias /webapps/project/static/;
        }

        location /media/ {
                alias /webapps/project/media/;
        }

        location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                                                              
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://project_prod;
        }

        listen 443 ssl;

        # SSL stuff here...

        if ($scheme != "https") {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        # PAGE SPEED

        pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
        pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
        pagespeed EnableFilters responsive_images;

        location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
        location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon" { }
}
```

Comment: did you reset gunicorn or wsgi?

Comment: yes, the build process always restarts NGINX and Gunicorn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx: How to keep double slashes in urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320774/nginx-how-to-keep-double-slashes-in-urls)

Comment: I think it is a different problem. I added the 'merge_slashes off' flag in NGINX and the slashes also stay in the URL, but NGINX just serves the root page / instead of the one that should be resolved. In the local django test server the /// resolve to the correct URL...