# nginx:- How to keep double slash in url?

Tags: nginx

We recently upgraded our Nginx version to 1.2.8. However, after the upgrade, if a URL contains double slashes, it is converting into a single one.

For example:

Original URL: https://www.url.com/filter2/date/filter2//filter3/Id

Converted URL: [https://www.url.com/filter2/date/filter2/filter3/Id"](https://www.url.com/filter2/date/filter2/filter3/Id%22)

Tried merge slash off but same result

Comment: Why do you need doubleslash at the end?

Comment: Not in the end after filter2

Comment: @user3775412 Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320774/nginx-how-to-keep-double-slashes-in-urls

Comment: @user3775412 I know. :-) I referred to the last double-slash, not the first.

Comment: @lukas.j No i already tried

Comment: @user3775412 For future questions you might have: add such information when posting a question. Everything you tried should be listed.